# Needs cannot open a package

Tags: packages

I have a package and notebook in the same directory, but `Needs` is throwing an error

> "Cannot open EField.m".

I have tried several variations of this.  I am using the following command in my notebook. The notebook and `EField.m` are in the same directory.

```
Needs["EKSModel`EFields`", "EField.m"]
```

The package is declared as:

```
BeginPackage["EKSModel`EFields`"]
```

Do we need to register packages when they are in the same directory?

Comment: Is the directory on `$Path`?

Answer (score 2):

The Notebook location is not automatically added to the package search path.

Try assembling the qualified file path with [`NotebookDirectory`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NotebookDirectory.html) and [`FileNameJoin`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FileNameJoin.html):

```
Needs["EKSModel`EFields`", FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "EField.m"}]]
```

Comment: Thanks Mr. Wizard - I used 

strESegment = NotebookDirectory[] <> "ElectrodeSegment.m"
strEFieldPath = NotebookDirectory[] <> "EField.m"

Get[strESegment]
Get[strEFieldPath]

Would there be any way to wrap this in a Try ... Catch or equivalent error checking?